# Who to Insert data into ODD/EVEN rows only in SQL

Tags: sql

I have one table with gender as one of the columns.
In gender column only M or F are allowed.
Now i want to sort the table so that while displaying the table in gender field M and F will come alternetivly.

I have Tried....
I have tried to create one(new) table with the same structure as my existing table.
Now using high leval insert i want to insert M to odd rows and F to even rows.
After that i want to join those two statements using union operator.
I am able to insert to  ( new ) the table only male or female but not to the even or odd rows...
Can any body help me regarding this....

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't consider a table to be "sorted". The SQL server may return the rows in any order depending on execution plan, index, joins etc. If you want a strict order you need to have an ordered column, like an identity column. Usually it is better to apply the desired sorting when selecting data.

However the interleaving of M and F is a little bit tricky, you need to use the `ROW_NUMBER` function.

Valid SQL Server code:

```
CREATE TABLE #GenderTable(
    [Name] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Gender] [char](1) NOT NULL
) 

-- Create sample data
insert into #GenderTable (Name, Gender) values
('Adam',        'M'),
('Ben',         'M'),
('Casesar',     'M'),
('Alice',       'F'),
('Beatrice',    'F'),
('Cecilia',     'F')

SELECT * FROM #GenderTable

SELECT * FROM #GenderTable
order by ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by gender order by name), Gender


DROP TABLE #GenderTable
```

This gives the output

```
Name        Gender
Adam        M
Ben         M
Casesar     M
Alice       F
Beatrice    F
Cecilia     F
```

and

```
Name        Gender
Alice       F
Adam        M
Beatrice    F
Ben         M
Cecilia     F
Casesar     M
```

If you use another DBMS the syntax may differ.

Comment: He will have to write `N` number of insert statements in this case, which is not a feasible solution for large datasets...

Comment: I don't think this requires any inserts, he is just doing those inserts to populate the data which the OP already has. This is a rather elegant solution that is possible with SQL Server (through the use of partition), but becomes a little more jumbled with MySQL

Comment: @mattedgod yes, you are right. But, I think creating a temporary table has only increased confusion. He should have gone with the original (any assumed) table name to have a clearer point of view :) Nice solution, BTW...

Comment: If only the OP had included the original table name :)

Comment: The temp table is there on purpose to create a complete working example with sample data that you can play with if you don't have access to the original data. The OP of course uses his own data instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do it would be to have two queries (one for M, one for F) and then join them together. The catch would be you would have to calculate the "rank" of each query and then sort accordingly.

Something like the following should do what you need:

```
select * from 
(select 
    @rownum:=@rownum+1 rank, 
    t.* 
from people_table t, 
    (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
where t.gender = 'M'
union 
select 
    @rownum:=@rownum+1 rank, 
    t.* 
from people_table t, 
    (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
where t.gender = 'F') joined
order by joined.rank, joined.gender;
```

Comment: for some reason I assumed this was mysql, I don't know why. If it is not, no guarantees this method of "ranking" the rows will work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **SQL Server**, you can seed your two tables with an `IDENTITY` column as follows.  Make one odd and one even and then union and sort by this column.

Note that you can only truly alternate if there are the same number of male and female records.  If there are more of one than the other, you will end up with non-alternating rows at the end.

```
CREATE TABLE MaleTable(Id INT IDENTITY(1,2) NOT NULL, Gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO MaleTable(Gender) SELECT 'M'
INSERT INTO MaleTable(Gender) SELECT 'M'
INSERT INTO MaleTable(Gender) SELECT 'M'

CREATE TABLE FemaleTable(Id INT IDENTITY(2,2) NOT NULL, Gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO FemaleTable(Gender) SELECT 'F'
INSERT INTO FemaleTable(Gender) SELECT 'F'
INSERT INTO FemaleTable(Gender) SELECT 'F'

SELECT u.Id
       ,u.Gender
  FROM (
        SELECT Id, Gender
          FROM FemaleTable
        UNION
        SELECT Id, Gender
          FROM MaleTable
        ) u 
 ORDER BY u.Id ASC
```

See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8784/1) for a working example

Comment: He will have to write `N` number of insert statements in this case, which is not a very good solution...

Comment: Here in the above case i have to create two tables write?

Comment: But i already have a table from which have data i just want to retrive the data in a specific format.